# ScriptSharp - post data as name-value collection

Tags: jquery, ajax, script#

I am trying to post data with Script# using jQuery.AjaxRequest method:

```
jQueryAjaxOptions options = new jQueryAjaxOptions();
options.Url = "/Server/Login.ashx";
options.Data = new LoginRequest(username, password);
jQuery.AjaxRequest<LoginResponse>(options);
```

How can I avoid the LoginRequest class to be generated?
Can I pass the data as some sort of name-value collection?
Or alternatively make LoginRequest "Imported"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the ScriptName attribute perhaps. Like this:

```
[Imported]
[IgnoreNamespace]
[ScriptName("Object")] // this will make Script# emit this as {}
public class LoginRequest
{
    public string username { get; set; }

    public string password { get; set; }
}
```

I'm just shooting from the hip here (I haven't tested this on my machine) but give that a try.

Comment: It worked for me thanks! I only had to make a change for LoginRequest to not have constructor: LoginRequest data = new LoginRequest(); data.Username = username; data.Password = password;

Comment: Great - hope you're enjoying Script# - we've really found it useful where I work.

Comment: You can add a ctor that takes a params object[] nameValuePairs along with a parameterless one ... this will let you pass in "username", username, "password", password to get a compact object literal: { username: username, password: password } ... hope that helps.